# Batch scripting: how to join two conditions to delete directories?

Tags: batch-file, directory, subdirectory

I'm working in a directory and would like my batch script to delete all sub-directories based on two conditions:

1. The subdirectory's name starts with `foo`.
2. The subdirectory was last modified more than 14 days ago.

So far, I can delete the sub-directories based on condition 1, and I can select the directories based on condition 2:

```
FOR /D %%i IN (C:\path\foo*) DO (rd /s /q "%%i")
```

and

```
Forfiles /d -14
```

How can I join the two conditions?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use the /M option @isdir meta variable.

Comment: Thanks for downvoting- it’s really, really useful. I deleted my other post because I thought that my question had evolved enough into something different. As for using the -M syntax, I tried experimenting with it and had no luck. So, thanks.

Comment: I never used `forfiles` before, so I read the `forfiles /?` help screen and after a couple minutes I wrote this: `cd C:\path & FORFILES /M foo* /D -14 /C "cmd /c if @isdir==TRUE rd /s /q @file"`. After I posted this comment, I downvoted the question! **`:/`**

Answer (score 1):

There are certain things (like working with dates) that you need to use VBScript instead of batch commands.  There is probably a way to do what you want in a .bat but combining multiple ANDs is trivial in .vbs.  Here is an example to delete subfolders.  You just need to supply the regex expression for "C:\path\foo*.

```
Dim oFSO, oFolder, oFolderCollection, iDaysOld, Date1, wsh, regex

iDaysOld = 14
Date1 = Date()

'Create FileSystemObject object to access the file system.

Set wsh = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Set oFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set regex = new regexp
regex.IgnoreCase = True
regex.Pattern = {sorry but you'll need to figure out the regex here}

'Get Folder object and Files
Set oFolder = oFSO.GetFolder(wsh.ExpandEnvironmentStrings(path)) 
Set oFolderCollection = oFolder.SubFolders

'Walk through each file in this folder collection. 
For each folder in oFolderCollection

If (folder.DateModified <= (Date() - iDaysOld)) And (regex.Execute(folder.path)) Then

' WARNING The following line will delete the folder and any subfolders or files. True means that it will delete read only too
folder.Delete(True)

End If
Next

'Remove the following line when running in production
'MsgBox "Deleted files.", vbOKOnly + vbInformation

'Clean up
Set oFSO = Nothing
Set oFolder = Nothing
Set oFolderCollection = Nothing
'End
```

Answer (score 1):

What about

```
forfiles /P C:\path\ /M foo* /S /D -14 /C "cmd /c if @isdir==TRUE echo rd /s /q @file"
```

Uses `forfiles` for date selection, recursive search, name pattern and a conditional to only select folders.